# How can I combine these 2 Oracle Queries from 1 table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one Oracle table that contains the daily counts for several activities.  I need to create a query that shows the sum of the daily activity for a month and the same month only for the previous year. So I would end up with 6 columns something like this:

year|month|SumOfCount|PreviousYear|PreviousMonth|PreSumOfCount

I have created these 2 SQL queries this one provides the information on the date parameters entered:

```
select extract(year from activitydate) as yr, extract(MONTH from 
activitydate) as mon, Sum(dicalls)
from updstats
Where ACTIVITYDATE BETWEEN TO_DATE (:STARTDATE,'MM/DD/YYYY') AND 
TO_DATE(:ENDDATE,'MM/DD/YYYY')
GROUP BY extract(year from activitydate), extract(MONTH from activitydate)
order by yr, mon
```

and this one provides the data for the previous date range:

```
select extract(year from activitydate) as Pyr, extract(MONTH from 
activitydate) as Pmon, Sum(dicalls)
from updstats
Where ACTIVITYDATE BETWEEN add_months(TO_DATE (:STARTDATE,'MM/DD/YYYY'),-12) 
AND add_months(TO_DATE(:ENDDATE,'MM/DD/YYYY'),-12)
GROUP BY extract(year from activitydate), extract(MONTH from activitydate)
order by Pyr, Pmon
```

I am stuck and cannot figure out how I could combine these 2 to give me the data set I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would join the result of the two tables on month and year

```
select  *
from    (
            select  extract(year from activitydate) as yr,
                    extract(month from activitydate) as mon,
                    Sum(dicalls)
            from    updstats
            where   activitydate between to_date(:STARTDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') and
                    to_date(:ENDDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
            group by  extract(year from activitydate),
                      extract(month from activitydate)
        ) ty
join    (
            select  extract(year from activitydate) as Pyr,
                    extract(month from activitydate) as Pmon,
                    Sum(dicalls)
            from    updstats
            where   activitydate between add_months(to_date(:STARTDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), -12)
                    and add_months(to_date(:ENDDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), -12)
            group by  extract(year from activitydate), 
                      extract(month from activitydate)
        ) ly
on      ty.yr = ly.Pyr + 1 and
        ty.mon = ly.Pmon
order by  ty.yr, ty.mon
```

The month will be the same, so you only have to make each year match with the previous one

Answer (score 1):

Get the sum of dicalls per month and year and use `lag` to get the value from the same month in the previous year. Use a `where` clause to filter for date ranges in the outer query. (This query outputs all the months and years in the table.)

```
select yr,mth,dicalls
,lag(yr) over(partition by mth order by yr) prev_yr
,lag(mth) over(partition by mth order by yr) prev_mth
,lag(dicalls) over(partition by mth order by yr) prev_dicalls
from (select sum(dicalls) as dicalls,extract(month from activitydate) as mth,extract(year from activitydate) as yr
      from updstats
      group by extract(month from activitydate),extract(year from activitydate)
     ) x
order by 1,2
```

Comment: You need to add the `where` clause to the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

You can join those two queries as subqueries with rownumber .

```
 select * from 
            (select extract(year from activitydate) as yr, 
            extract(MONTH from activitydate) as mon, 
            Sum(dicalls),
           row_number() over(partition by extract(year from activitydate),extract(MONTH from activitydate) order by extract(year from activitydate),extract(MONTH from activitydate)) rn1
            from updstats Where ACTIVITYDATE BETWEEN TO_DATE (:STARTDATE,'MM/DD/YYYY') AND TO_DATE(:ENDDATE,'MM/DD/YYYY')
            GROUP BY extract(year from activitydate), extract(MONTH from activitydate)
            order by yr, mon) as n 
       join (select extract(year from activitydate) as Pyr, 
           extract(MONTH from activitydate) as Pmon,             
           Sum(dicalls),
           row_number() over(partition by extract(year from activitydate) ,extract(MONTH from activitydate) order by extract(year from activitydate) ,extract(MONTH from activitydate) as rn2
            from updstats  Where ACTIVITYDATE BETWEEN add_months(TO_DATE (:STARTDATE,'MM/DD/YYYY'),-12) 
            AND add_months(TO_DATE(:ENDDATE,'MM/DD/YYYY'),-12)
            GROUP BY extract(year from activitydate), extract(MONTH from activitydate)
            order by Pyr, Pmon)) as p on (n.rn1=p.rn2) order by n.yr,n.mon
```

Answer (score 0):

And just because no one has answered via a CTE, here you go

```
with tbl_A as (
select extract(year from activitydate) as yr, extract(MONTH from 
activitydate) as mon, Sum(dicalls)
from updstats
Where ACTIVITYDATE BETWEEN TO_DATE (:STARTDATE,'MM/DD/YYYY') AND 
TO_DATE(:ENDDATE,'MM/DD/YYYY')
GROUP BY extract(year from activitydate), extract(MONTH from activitydate)
order by yr, mon
),
tbl_B as(

select extract(year from activitydate) as Pyr, extract(MONTH from 
activitydate) as Pmon, Sum(dicalls)
from updstats
Where ACTIVITYDATE BETWEEN add_months(TO_DATE (:STARTDATE,'MM/DD/YYYY'),-12) 
AND add_months(TO_DATE(:ENDDATE,'MM/DD/YYYY'),-12)
GROUP BY extract(year from activitydate), extract(MONTH from activitydate)
order by Pyr, Pmon
)
select * from tbl_A a inner join tbl_B b on a.yr = b.yr and a.mon = b.mon;
```